# Sparkjava redirect while keeping the browser URL

Tags: spark-java

I have a sparkjava server app running, it serves a static HTML page using this line:

```
staticFiles.location("/public");
```

If you go to http://example.com, you will see the HTML page. Now, I want to redirect users from other paths to my homepage, while keeping the browser URL. For example, if you visit http://example.com/message/123, you will still see the HTML page, while the browser URL stays http://example.com/message/123. So redirect.get() won't work here.

Comment: Why can't you just serve the same HTML page for the other non-homepage paths?

Comment: I use staticFiles.location("/public"); to serve the static content at default location "/". Is there a way to also serve it at a different location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to serve the same file from different paths, you can do as follows (it looks long but it's pretty simple):

Assuming your project's structure is:

```
src
  java
    main
      resources
        public
        templates   (optional folder)
```

On `GET` request to your homepage a static HTML file that resides in `/public` is served. Let's call this file `index.html`.

Now you want to register additional path(s) to serve this file. If you use TemplateEngine you can do it easily. Actually, you'll refer to `index.html` both as a static file and as a template (with no parameters).

Template engine lets you create the served HTML page dynamically by passing it a map of key-value pairs that you can reference in the template on runtime. But in your case, it will be much simpler because you want to serve a page as-is, statically. Therefore you'll pass an empty map:

```
Spark.get("/message/123", (req, res) ->
    new ModelAndView(new HashMap(),
                     "../public/index"),
                     new ThymeleafTemplateEngine()
);
```

- `Thymeleaf` is just an example here, Spark supports [few template engines](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#views-and-templates). For each one of them, you can find in the documentation a simple github example of how to use it. For example, [This is](https://github.com/perwendel/spark-template-engines/tree/master/spark-template-thymeleaf) the Thymeleaf one.
- The path `../public/index` is because Spark is looking for templates in the `templates` folder, and you want to target `public/index.html` as the template.
- You'll find the class `ThymeleafTemplateEngine` in the github link.
- Of course you'll have to add the chosen template engine dependency to the project's `pom.xml` file.

As a result, `GET` requests to both `http://example.com` and `http://example.com/message/123` will serve `index.html` while keeping the requested URL.

Comment: Works great! Thanks!

Comment: @SHG Can I do this without using a TemplatingEngine, it doesnt seem that a templating engine has much to do with the problem ?

Comment: @PaulTaylor Do you also have the same restriction regarding the URL that must not change (as the OP had)? Because if you don't, you can just use a normal redirect.

Comment: @SHG yes I do have same restriction

Comment: @PaulTaylor I tried to look for a more elegant solution but couldn't find anything that uses Spark Java features. You can use many other redirection methods but these are out of Spark Java scope. I do agree that it could be a nice feature.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the index.html file into a string and serve it. This is what I ended up doing.

If your application runs from compiled .class files:

```java
URL url = getClass().getResource("public/index.html");
String indexDotHTML = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(url.toURI())));

get("/message/123", "text/html", (req, res) -> indexDotHTML);
```

if your application runs from a jar: (solution uses Guava as a helper)

```java
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;


InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/public/index.html");
String indexDotHTML = new String(ByteStreams.toByteArray(in));

get("/message/123", "text/html", (req, res) -> indexDotHTML);
```