# With Java Spark how do I send a html file as a repsonse

Tags: java, spark-java

How do I use spark to return an existing page

I have the example working where I just return some text

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Hello World");
    }
}
```

I have changed to

```
import spark.Service;
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        staticFiles.externalLocation("C:\\HtmlFolder\\"); // Static files
        init();
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Report00001.html");
    }
}
```

and I want it to display the contents of HtmlFolder\Report00001.hml but it just displays Report0001.html

I cannot see any examples showing how to do this

So if I place a index.html within C:\HtmlFolder\ then that is now displayed when open browser at http://localhost:4567/ but I cannnot see how do a mapping for get requests to display other files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that `C:\\HtmlFolder\\`is not in your classpath.

To serve external resources (out of the classpath) you need to use `staticFiles.externalLocation() + System.getProperty()`

**Example:**

```
staticFiles.externalLocation(System.getProperty("myDir"));
```

Check [Spark Static Files Documenation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#static-files) if you need to know more about this.

**EDITED:**

Configure external locatios as above and the, in your get, do something like

`get("/hello", (req, res) -> {res.redirect("/Report00001.html");});`

*(I'm not sure now if shoul be `"/Report00001.html"` or `"Report00001.html"`)*

Comment: My example does that, and I have already the docs it doesnt show me how to serve a file back as response

Comment: @paul-taylor All the static files are returned through the get method. To see your html, simply type the direction in your url, or redirect to it.

Comment: can you please give me an example of how to code a get call so it returns such a file

Comment: I tried get("/hello", (req, res) -> new File("FixSongsReport00001")); but still didnt work

Comment: thanks, but tried it and complains ';' is required ?

Comment: so add it to `res.redirect("/Report00001.html")`. I have no tested the code

Comment: I have tried that, cannot get it to work wherever I put it, I'm not familiar with the Java 8 -> syntax.

Comment: ok i have working with get("/hello", (request, response) -> {response.redirect("Report00001.html");return "";}); thankyou, but  sure I want a redirect could I not make it display this page but keep the url displayed as localhost/hello rather than it becoming localhost/Report00001.html

Comment: yes, you can too. Take a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44401973/sparkjava-redirect-while-keeping-the-browser-url

Answer (score 1):

It seems that

```
get("/hello", (req, res) -> "Report00001.html");
```

returns a single string. If that string is supposed to be a file - you probably have to **open** the file, collect its content, and return that content as string.

Comment: Yes, but surely spark-java has a way to do that for you ?

Comment: because if I just did as you recommend then externalFiles() would serve no purpose

Answer (score 1):

Static content only can be served using the URL of the actual file like you mention in your original question. If you want to map this static file to a specific endpoint, you need to read the content of the file programatically and return the String.

An other method would be to implement your own template engine that just returns the content of the HTML file even though it might be a bit overkill it should be simple enough to do.